# ERROR - No Cordova Plugin added to Neutrinos Platform

Tags: android, cordova, neutrinos-platform

When running Android Emulator in Neutrinos Studio latest version, I get this error:

> Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use 'Cordova
>   platform add'.

Is it that Cordova platform not installed in my system? I used the default dashboard app from marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly ensure following steps are performed.

1. Run "Initialize" from the action drop-down.
2. Check if 'www' present in the current working directory else Run this command "mkdir www" (In Console).
3. Run "Initialize Mobile" from the action drop-down.
4. Run "Android Emulate"